Page break table before <tr> - breaks whole table
I have an JSF application which has the ability to create a PDF with iText 5. Now, our customer wants to have page breaks in specific places - basically he wants a page break inside a table. As page-break-before did not work directly with <tr>, I added a <div> element before each <tr>, and added page-break-before: always CSS to these divs, which is adding a page break, but before the whole table.
So lets say I have 3 <tr>, then it would generate 3 blank pages before the table.
Is this general behaviour or why are my page breaks inserted before the whole table?
I'm aware of the AreaBreak from iText, but as we generate a HTML string with Elements and the document is created at the end with this string, I'm afraid I cannot use it. I tried adding css with @media print, screen { ... } as well, but this did as well not change anything concerning results.
I have tried adding display: block and/or page-break-inside: auto to the table, which did as well not change anything. Wrapping the table in a div neither.

You're dependent on what HTML iText5 supports. I've tried to look up the documentation, but couldn't find it. I do see that iText5 is EOL. Anyway, my tip is: You stand a much better change of receiving an answer if you include a link to the iText5 documentation. Note that the auto-generated API documentation doesn't count.

"why are my page breaks inserted before the whole table?" - that's the result of you messing up the HTML. You CAN NOT "insert divs before the tr", that is invalid HTML. If you feed that to a browser, it will create all three divs before the table - see https://jsfiddle.net/op1fvem8/ - and your iText 5 appears to apply similar error correction.

If you are adding <div> before <tr>, than your HTML becomes invalid, as <table> can not have child <div>. It will be the same in Browser rendering (Add <div style="height: 2px; padding: 2px; background-color: red"> and will see it outside table)

What you can do (if possible) - have separate tabels in places where page brake must appear
